# Java 6 : ProcessBuilder inheritIO for java 6

Tags: java, processbuilder

I am downgrading a code from Java 7 to Java 6 and in the code I have found somes uses of `ProcessBuilder#inheritIO()` method which does not exists in Java 6.

Is there any to create the bahavior of `inheritIO` in Java 6 ?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, but you'll need to do it by hand. Get the streams from the `Process` and pipe them to the current process' streams.